# Cosmos Db (need any sort of iteration mechanism)

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

want to check my document have same value in object A for eg:

```
    {
"id": "1234-wrew-1234314"
"_ts": 1672840679
"A": [
        {
            "Id": "123",
            "values": 167273168512
        },
        {
            "Id": "1234",
            "values": 1672731685
        },
        {
            "Id": "123456",
            "values": 1673461685
        }
    ]
}
```

have this document now i want to check all **values** have same value or not is there any way to do this?
what i already tried :

```
select EXISTS(
    SELECT VALUE n
    FROM n IN c.A
    WHERE c.A[0].values= c.A[1].values) as a
    from c 
 where c.id ="1234-wrew-1234314"
```

its working fine if i have only 2 records in object A but i want generic solution to handle any number of records in object.
i also try with **array_contain** but its not working.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I messed around with this for a while and could not get it to work.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean. If you are saying you want to compare any two documents, for all existing properties... that's not really a thing, since any document could have any number of properties. Same with arrays: there is no built-in mechanism to compare one array to another. You'd have to build custom code to do this.

Comment: @DavidMakogon my bad i think my question wasn't clear, i'm not talking about comparing two documents i want to do this within the same document . the above mentioned example object A have three entries i want to check whether all the entries have same value or not through query in cosmos like :  values[0] = value[1] = value =[2] 
dont want to use index like value[0] = value[1] want to compare all values in object A

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you need?

```
SELECT d.MaxValue = d.MinValue ? 'All the same' : 'Not the same' 
FROM 
(
    SELECT MAX(a.values) AS MaxValue ,
           MIN(a.values) AS MinValue
    FROM   c
    JOIN   a IN c.A
    WHERE  c.id = "1234-wrew-1234314"    
) d
```

Comment: Thanks for the help yes it works perfect but i'm looking for a solution which i use in my existing query, want something like your solution to use in **where clause** .
actually don't want to change my whole implementation .